# Using 'all' in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I am new to Makefile and I wrote this one to compile a kernel created by me 
this is the file hierarchy for my source tree created by `ls -R`. I tried solutions in similar questions.

```
.:
kernel  Makefile

./kernel:
arch  drivers  include

./kernel/arch:
i686-elf

./kernel/arch/i686-elf:
boot.s  linker.ld  main.c  Makefile

./kernel/drivers:
vga

./kernel/drivers/vga:
vga.c  vga.o

./kernel/include:
vga

./kernel/include/vga:
vga.h
```

this is the content of `./Makefile`

```
VPATH = kernel kernel/* kernel/*/*
TARGET = i686-elf
CC = gcc
INCDIR = -I kernel/include/ -I kernel/include/*
kERNEL = opal2
CFLAGS = -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions
LDFLAGS = -T linker.ld -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib -lgcc
AS = as
include kernel/arch/$(TARGET)/Makefile
.PHONY: help all
help:
        @echo "This is help"
all: $(KERNEL)

$(KERNEL):$(OBJECTS)
        $(TARGET)-$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(KERNEL).bin
$(OBJECTS):%.o :%.c
        $(TARGET)-$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
$(objects): %.o: %.s
        $(TARGET)-$(AS) $< -o $@
```

please note that I created a cross compiler and cross binutils called that are prefixed with i686-elf- and they are included in environmental variables and I am sure that they are working
and this is the contents of the `./kernel/arch/i686*elf/Makefile`

```
OBJECTS := $(OBJECTS) boot.o main.o
```

I am sure that I used *TABS* instead of spaces and as you see there is nothing built at all 
EDIT:
after fixings the little typo `kERNEL` to be `KERNEL`
I got the following error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `boot.c', needed by `boot.o'.  Stop.
```

shouldn't kernel/*/* allow VPATH to inclucde kernel/arch/i686-elf and makefile notice that boot.s exist and build it

Comment: note your `$(KERNEL)` is not an actual file created. This shouldn't cause the problem, but it's still not good ... either put `$(KERNEL)` in the `.PHONY:` prerequisite list, so `make` knows it is not a file ... or just set it to the actual file created for the kernel.

Comment: this error appeared 
make: *** No rule to make target `boot.c', needed by `boot.o'.  Stop.

Comment: also `objects` != `OBJECTS`, which is what is causing the `%.s` rule for assembling things to never apply...

Answer (score 2):

The root cause it doesn't do *anything* is probably just the typo in your variable name, like Marc B pointed out: `kERNEL` instead of `KERNEL`.

With this Makefile, you could still experience unexpected behaviour: Just a `touch opal2` in the directory would stop it from working unless you `rm opal2` again. Target names that are *not* actual file names must therefore be put as a prerequisite of the special target `.PHONY`, so `make` knows they have to be recreated *each and every time*, because there is no actual file for `make` to check the timestamp and determine whether it is outdated.

Of course, you want to avoid that for most targets, so `make` doesn't do unnecessary work. So, just use the file created by a target as the actual target instead of a "phony" name.

Next issue: This line

```
$(OBJECTS):%.o :%.c
```

is wrong. There's only one colon expected there, to separate the target name from its prerequisites. It looks like you want a simple *pattern rule* here like

```
%.o: %.c
```

meaning any target ending with `.o` will have a prerequisite of the same name, just ending in `.c`. I don't see `$(OBJECTS)` actually defined anywhere, so it's just an empty variable anyways.

**edit**: As of Chris Dodd's comment, the above *is* valid syntax, but only meaningful iff the variable is not empty. So another source of the problem might lie in the fact you get `$(OBJECTS)` set to something in your included Makefile, but not `$(objects)`.

I'd really suggest you to browse through the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) ... it might seem though at first, but it's really helpful. One key issue with writing Makefiles when you're coming from coding in e.g. [c](/questions/tagged/c) is that a Makefile is declarative -- you give `make` a couple of rules and it will figure out itself what do do, in what order. It takes a bit of time to get a grasp on the concepts.

Comment: Two colons makes a static pattern rule (as opposed to a general pattern rule), which should work.  The problem he has is tha `$(objects)` != `$(OBJECTS)` in the rule for assembling `.s` files, so it never applies...

Comment: Ah ok ... never used that one. Still, as far as I can see, neither of those contains anything? Can't check the `include` of course.

Comment: `$(OBJECTS)` is set in the included makefile.  `$(objects)` is never set to anything, so is an empty string